# No matching declaration found after argument-dependent lookup in remix IDE

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-debugging

I'm getting this error in remix:

```
"TypeError: No matching declaration found after argument-dependent lookup. require(_spender.call.value(msg.value)(_data));
^-----^ "

function approveAndCall(address payable _spender, uint256 _value, bytes memory _data) public payable returns (bool) {    
  require(_spender != address(this));   
  this.approve(_spender, _value);    
  require(_spender.call.value(msg.value)(_data));    
  return true;   
}
```

Please I need help on how to resolve this. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When you use the `call` function, you can control the returned success condition as a `bool` and check if the `call` succeed or not.

```
function approveAndCall(address payable _spender, uint256 _value, bytes memory _data) public payable returns (bool) {    
    require(_spender != address(this));   
    this.approve(_spender, _value);    
    (bool success, ) = _spender.call.value(msg.value)(_data);
    require(success);
    return true;   
}
```

From [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#members-of-addresses):

> In order to interface with contracts that do not adhere to the ABI, or
>   to get more direct control over the encoding, the functions `call`,
>   `delegatecall` and `staticcall` are provided. They all take a single
>   `bytes memory` parameter and return the success condition (as a
>   `bool`) and the returned data (`bytes memory`).